# twitter embedded timeline in WordPress causes problems in ie8

Tags: twitter, internet-explorer-8

I pasted the Twitter generated code for an embedded timeline in a Text widget in WordPress. It causes a rendering issue in IE8 whereby links are being replaced by the tweet button. 
Screenshot:
http://www.48thave.com/clients/ntp/shotshow/test-twitter.png
WordPress test page:
http://shotshow.com/test-twitter/
Code:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" style="border:0"  href="https://twitter.com/nssfshotshow" height="300" data-widget-id="336534911341166596" data-chrome="noheader nofooter noborders transparent">Tweets by @nssfshotshow</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

Anyone have a solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved today by Twitter patching a recent release of their script.
https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/21893